# How to make css not repeat same class?

Tags: css, sass

```
.class-action:hover, .class-action.activeOne {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.class-action.activeOne {  
  margin: 3px 0px; 
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

is there a way to stack these css code? I dont want to repeat same class again. I want all four style for "**.class-action.activeOne**" and only above 2 style when "**.class-action:hover**"

other option is below, but it repeats the css

```
.class-action:hover {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.class-action.activeOne {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold; 
  margin: 3px 0px; 
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply nest your selectors:

```
.class-action {
    &:hover,
    &.activeOne {
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    &.activeOne {  
        margin: 3px 0px; 
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }
}
```